# Autocommand when writing to files in the arglist

Tags: autocmd

Is it possible to create an autocommand that executes whenever one 
of the files in the arglist is written to?

Comment: Yes. Start by reading `:help autocmd` and `:help BufWrite`.

Answer (score 3):

There is not a specific Autocommand event for writes to the arglist files. What you can do is create a function that checks if the file is in the arglist and then set that to the `BufWrite` event. So all buffer writes would trigger this function, but only arglist'd files would actually do anything.

You can use `bufname("%")` to find the current buffer's name, and then use `argv()` and `argc()` to find the arglist entries.

```
function! IsBufInArgs()
  let c = 0
  while c <= argc()
    if argv(c) == bufname("%")
      return 1
    endif
    let c += 1
  endwhile

  return 0
endfunction

function! DoOnlyWithArg()
  if IsBufInArgs() == 1
    echo "Do something here"
  endif
endfunction

autocmd BufWrite * :call DoOnlyWithArg()
```